# Copy data between tables with some static values

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to copy data from one table to another. Doing so, I'd like to set manually some static values that will override data from source table. Here is example:

```sql
INSERT INTO users (id_usr, name, description, mod_date, user_type) 
SELECT id_usr, name, description, '2014-03-19 15:15:09', 'public'
 FROM users_temp
 WHERE user_type="" OR user_type IS NULL;
```

'Datetime' string and `'public'` are those static values.

I'd like to know if it is possible, because on Android phone(SQLite from external native library) it doesn't copy any records, but on Windows it works fine.

Comment: This statement looks perfectly fine. Does all the other SQL stuff done with the native library work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. My `users_temp` table was actually a virtual table created from file. While creating that virtual table I have defined wrong charset. It caused that, at the end of every value there was added some kind of white character and condition:

```sql
WHERE user_type="" OR user_type IS NULL;
```

was never fulfilled.

After fixing the problem, statement is executing correctly.